# which one is more time complexity between TSP or CPP?

Tags: time-complexity, traveling-salesman, chinese-postman

What's the difference between traveling-salesman problem and Chinese postman problem From a Time complexity perspective? 
I mean which one is more time complexity between TSP and CPP ?

Comment: You're probably asking for a complexity of a solution not a problem and it depends on which solution will you choose.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: In general, I want to know which of the following is more time complex?

Answer (score 0):

Chinese postman problem can be solved in polynomial time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem), TSP is NP complete (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

So unless P=NP, the travelling salesman problem has a higher time complexity.